# Measurability of pre-image of essential supremum

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory

I've been wondering if the following statement is true.

> Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{F})$ be a measurable space, and let $f: \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a bounded measurable function. Let $\mathcal{P}(\Omega)$ be the set of all probability measures on this space. Given $\mu \in \mathcal{P}(\Omega)$, define
> $$ S := \{w \in \Omega: f(\omega) = \text{ess} \sup_\mu f\}.$$
> Then, $S$ is measurable.

My first attempt:

> Let $a^* = \text{ess}\sup_\mu f := \inf_{a \in \mathbb{R}} [\mu(\{\omega \in \Omega : f(\omega) > a\}) = 0]$. Then, $a^* < \infty$ since $f$ is bounded and there exists a sequence of real numbers $\{a_n\}_{n\geq 1}$ converging to $a^*$ from above. Taking $S_n = \{\omega \in \Omega: f(\omega) > a_n\}$, we have that $S_n \in \mathcal{F}$ since it is a pre-image of $(a_n, \infty]$ under $f$.

From here, can we say that $ S = \cup_{n\geq 1} S_n$?

If that's the case then we should be able to say that $S \in \mathcal{F}$, because $\mathcal{F}$ is closed under countable union. But I'm not sure if $S = \cup_{n\geq 1} S_n$ is true.

Edit: I removed the statement about $\nu \in \mathcal{P}(\Omega)$ that was not making sense.

Comment: $\nu$ is not defined on $\mathcal F$.

Comment: Oh you're right. I wanted to mean $\nu(S) = 1$ and $\nu(R) = 0 ~\forall R \in \mathcal{F} \backslash S$.

Comment: The doesn't define $\nu$. $mathcal F \setminus S$ does not make sense.

Answer (score 1):

The proof is much simpler. For any real number $a_* \in \mathbb{R}$, the set
\begin{align}
S=\{\omega \in \Omega: f(\omega)=a_*\} \, ,
\end{align}
is measurable simply because $f$ is measurable and $\{a_*\}$ is a closed subset of $\mathbb{R}$. Choose $a_* =\mathrm{ess}\sup f$ and you are done.

Edit: As mentioned in the comments, this is not enough to show that $\nu$ is a probability measure. You need to define it on the remaining sets of the sigma algebra $\mathcal{F}$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. If I define $\nu$ by $\nu(S) = 1$ and $\nu(R) = 0 ~\forall R \in \mathcal{F}\backslash S$ does it suffice?

Comment: $S$ is one set $\mathcal F$ is a family of sets. So your definition of $\nu$ makes no sense. @hcdg2988

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I think maybe OP meant $\mathcal{F}\setminus\{S\}$. That still does not work.